# Variable in single quote

Tags: php

I have a code:

```
$str = 'some code';
$String = 'Some params  , This is  {$str}';
$String = str_replace('\'', "\"", $String);
$array = explode(',', $String);

var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
' This is  {$str}'
```

How can i get a string `' This is some code'` without using double quotes in `$String = 'Some params  , This is  {$str}';`? 
Is there any function? str_replace doesn't work.

EDIT:
Code above is example. A special case of my code.
I mean code like:

```
$str1 = 'some code 1';
$str2 = 'some code 2';
$str3 = 'some code 3';
$str = '{$str1}  ...  {$str2} ... {$str3}  ';
$result = preg_match_all('/({\$\S*})/',$str,$res);

foreach ($res[0] as $value){
    $arr_replace = ['{$','}'];
    $value_replaced = str_replace($arr_replace, "",$value);
    $str = str_replace($value,$$value_replaced,$str);
}
var_dump($str);
```

Is there a simpler method?

Comment: And what's the problem with double quotes?

Comment: You could use `$String = str_replace('{$str}', $str, $String);`

Comment: Actually there's a bit more complicated code. I get the $String variable from an array. And there's a value in single quotes.

Comment: This option is appropriate in this particular case, but there may be a dynamic variable name in this string.

Comment: Looks as though you are looking for a form of template engine - find the {$...} bits and use the ... to lookup a variable and replace it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the variables in, you can do one of 4 things:

1. **Double quotes**

   ```
   $str = 'some code';
   $String = "Some params  , This is  {$str}";
   ```

Apparently you do not want to do it, so we are going to option 2:

2. **Concatenation**

   ```
   $str = 'some code';
   $String = 'Some params  , This is  ' . $str;
   ```
3. **`str_replace`**
   As @Nick pointed out:

   ```
   $String = str_replace('{$str}', $str, $String);
   ```
4. **Heredoc**

   ```
   $str = 'some code';
   $String = <<<EOT
   Some params  , This is $str
   EOT;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need this, but you can try my code.

You can use `str_replace` also.

```
<?php

$str = 'some code';

$String = 'Some params  , This is  {$str}';

$String = preg_replace('/{\$str}/',$str ,$String);

//$String = str_replace('{$str}',$str ,$String);

$array = explode(',', $String);

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$String = 'Some params  , This is '.$str;
```

in place of

```
$String = 'Some params  , This is  {$str}';
```